# Questions about categories

Tags: nsdate, categories

> I want to do is produce a simple NSDate date in addition to would like
>   to add methods to add and subtract.

```
Date * myDate = [NSDate date]; // today
NSLog ("10 days after:%@", [myDate addToDays: 10]);
```

================= category ==================

```
@implementation NSDate (AddDate)
 - (NSDate *)addToDays:addToDays{
     NSDate *returnDate = [***HowGetmyDate*** dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*addToDays];

    return returnDate;
}
```

how get (myDate)?

The base date need not necessarily today.

Comment: Not directly related, but: this code is wrong anyway. Not all days are 24 hours long. Some are 23 or 25.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `self` to get your date object.
Category is the extension of the original class, you can operate/implement it as the original one.

```
@implementation NSDate (AddDate)
 - (NSDate *)addToDays:addToDays{
     NSDate *returnDate = [self dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*addToDays];

    return returnDate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
It is a very simple way